# How do I force "Compatibility View" ON in IE9 on a page with a proper Doc Type?

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-9, cross-browser, reportviewer

I have a site that is nearly all standards compliant, and expects to be that way across all browsers.  However, I have a specific page on my site that I want to render in a standards compliant way in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari, but due to a very annoying issue involving Zoom Levels in the Microsoft SSRS Report Viewer 10.0.0.0 control ([See here for a more complete description](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vsreportcontrols/thread/9ed8910f-bba1-428b-b8ad-bd9cbcbd53a7)), I need to render the page in Compatibility View mode in IE9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For IE9, add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` or add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">` as first line in your page. See http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm for details.

Comment: I think this forces on IE9 standards mode, which is exactly the opposite of what I want.  I want to force ON compatibility mode (in IE9), even though I have a valid doctype declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the meta tag does not seem to cause the page to render in compatibility view.  It simply renders in IE8 standards mode because my doctype is correct :).  - This is the behavior I am trying to turn on automatically on this particular page http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Compatibility-View-in-Internet-Explorer-9 if that helps.

Comment: Never mind, it seems I had to close IE9, each time I was testing a different scenario.  Otherwise, it seemed it liked to use the same behavior.  Not sure what was going on there.  Thanks!